# angular 2+ - set class or style on multiple focus input element

Tags: angular

I went to set a class or style on more input element when the input on focus.

For example, if only a input element:

```
<span [ngClass]=["control"? "classA":"classB"]>
    <input type="text" (foucs)="control=true" [ngClass]=["control"? "classC":"classD"]>
</span>
```

when the more input element, need more `control` parameter:

```
<span [ngClass]=["control_1"? "classA":"classB"]>
    <input type="text" (foucs)="control=true" [ngClass]=["control_1"? "classC":"classD"]>
</span>
<span [ngClass]=["control_2"? "classA":"classB"]>
    <input type="text" (foucs)="control=true" [ngClass]=["control_2"? "classC":"classD"]>
</span>
.
.
.
```

Has any way to do this, a parameter for more input element, like when `(focus)` return a `this` element.

Comment: Could you do it with a CSS class instead of having to do it individually on each element? Like this: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/

Comment: oh! think! It's great for `input` element. I also need to change the span structure of the parent layer at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

So to achieve exactly as you're asking you would do the following:

```
<span [ngClass]="{ 'classA': control, 'classB': !control }">
    <input type="text" (focus)="control=true" (blur)="control=false" [ngClass]="{ 'classC': control, 'classD': !control }">
</span>
```

*Pay close attention to how you interpolate a class property (quotes vs no quotes)*

*Also, you had a lot of mistakes with your spelling and general use of directives. You most likely need to visit the documentation.*

Comment: When I have a lot of `input` element, I need to set a lot of control variables, like `control_1`, `control_2`.... . This doesn't seem to be a good way? Think, I am thinking about how to use directives to achieve.